# sktime understanding the data format and error message

Tags: python, pandas, classification, sktime

I am trying to do a classification of time series data and came across sktime which offers many algorithms that can be used to classify time series.

However, I only manage to make RandomIntervalSpectralForest run. All other algorithms give me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17944/639170790.py in <module>
     12     cboss_params={"n_parameter_samples": 25, "max_ensemble_size": 5},
     13 )
---> 14 clf.fit(X_sk, y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    353             name = ibase.maybe_extract_name(name, data, type(self))
    354 
--> 355             if is_empty_data(data) and dtype is None:
    356                 # gh-17261
    357                 warnings.warn(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py in is_empty_data(data)
    794     is_none = data is None
    795     is_list_like_without_dtype = is_list_like(data) and not hasattr(data, "dtype")
--> 796     is_simple_empty = is_list_like_without_dtype and not data
    797     return is_none or is_simple_empty
    798 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The code I am trying to run first takes a normal csv and turns it into a pandas dataframe with row for the observations and columns as time points. Then I am using sktime's utility function to turn this dataframe into one that can be used by sktime and is nested:
`X_sk = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)`
If I am now running:

```
from sktime.classification.hybrid import HIVECOTEV2
hc2 = HIVECOTEV2()
hc2.fit(X_sk, pd.Series(y))
```

I am getting the above mentioned error. The RandomIntervalSpectralForest however runs with exactly the same data set.
I have compared the sample code and data set given on https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.classification.hybrid.HIVECOTEV1.html with my dataset and can't find any difference. The sample code runs for me, but I am lost figuring out why my code doesn't run.

I am trying to recreate the problem with another data set and will edit the post once I have a working example.